# How to create a variable number of pthreads?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

A part of a programming assignment I have at college specifies:

> for the  threads, initialize a large array of `pthread_t*` in `main()` and dynamically create `pthread_t` for each new student using `malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)`.

Seems simple enough. All I would have to do is something like:

```
pthread_t *pthreadArray = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * userInputSize);
```

to create a variable number of threads. However, we are not given a `userInputSize`. How is this possible then? If I were to just do:

```
pthread_t *pthreadArray = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
```

wouldn't that only give me a single pthread to work with? I feel as though this must be an issue in the programming instructions. Any ideas?

Comment: "*create pthread_t for each new student*": So your `userInputSize` should be the number of "*students*", whatever that means in the context of the assignment.

Comment: @uneven_mark, I assume the total number of students are not known before the first thread is started.

Comment: @HAL9000 Then the proper thing to do is using `realloc` whenever a new element must be added and there is no free space in the current allocation, but I think the wording of the assignment indicates that you are to simply define a large static array of sufficiently large number once, and simply assume that this number will never be exceeded.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with threads, it's just a question about arrays.

Answer (score 2):

So just do as the assignment says:

> for the threads, initialize a large array of `pthread_t*` in `main()`

```
/* Large number */
const size_t max_threads = 100;

/* Large array of pointers with every element initialized to zero */ 
pthread_t *student_threads[max_threads] = {};

size_t thread_count = 0;
```

> and dynamically create `pthread_t` for each new student using
>   `malloc(sizeof(pthread_t))`

```
pthread_t *new_student = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
```

What is not written is what you do with `new_student`. It is indeed a pointer to a single `pthread_t`. Just put the pointer in the next unused slot in your array:

```
/* Find next unused spot in array (with value==NULL) */
size_t i = 0
while (i < max_threads && student_threads[i])
   i++;

/* assign value to that spot */
student_threads[i] = new_student;
thread_count++;
```

Remember to add error checking where appropriate. And release all resources when you are finished with them.

That includes setting `student_threads[i]=NULL` whenever you call `free(student_threads[i])` so you know which slots in array are unused.